# HTML tag select option value returned as undefined

Tags: javascript, php, html, undefined

When I try to print the value of the option selected in the `<div>` tag I get undefined as a result.
This is the html code:

```
<div id="locations">
</div>

<button id="button" onclick="showSensors()">Show sensors in the city</button>

<p>Sensors in City: <span id="sensorsInCity"></span></p>
```

The options in the `<div>` element are created from a php script as such:

```
echo '<select id="selectCity">';
  foreach($resp as $sensor)
  {
    echo '<option value=' . $sensor['id'] . '>' . $sensor['id'] . '</option>';
  }
  echo '</select>';
```

This code is correct as they appear just fine both on the browser and the inspector as the options to select from.
This is the javascript code I use to get the selected option:

```
<script>
function showSensors(){
    var option = document.getElementById("selectCity").text;
    console.log(option);
    document.getElementById("sensorsInCity").innerHTML = "";
    var xhttp;
    xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("sensorsInCity").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "sparql.php?q="+option, true);
    xhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

I am trying to send it to another php script but when I `console.log` it I get `undefined`

Comment: `var option = document.getElementById("selectCity").value;`

Comment: try this: `var e = document.getElementById("selectCity"); var option = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;` source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/get-selected-value-in-dropdown-list-using-javascript

Comment: For some reason @u_mulder 's comment worked I thought I had tried that. Seems so stupid right now.